# Is there an alternative download location for Scala?

Tags: scala

I've been trying for awhile to grab the .MSI or .ZIP off http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/distrib/files/*, but it's extremely slow and actually stops downloading after awhile. I've searched for mirrors, but even places like Softpedia merely link back to scala-lang.org.

I was able to grab scala-library.jar from Akka.io, but I don't think that's sufficient for using the language (or I'm not instantiating it incorrectly with `java -jar`?).

Ideas?

Comment: This should be reopened. This definitely helped me. And scala-lang official downloads are still super slow after two years of this question being asked.

Comment: 2016, still slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download [The Typesafe Stack](http://www.typesafe.com/stack)

If you are on Mac OS-X and is using [homebrew](http://brew.sh) you can use

```
% brew install scala
% brew install typesafe activator
% brew install sbt
```

(or the eqvivalent port)

Comment: Thank you! That stack includes the Scala Programming Language Setup program and I've got it working now.